# check to see if a row is selected by using a JButton

Tags: jtable, jbutton, actionlistener, listselectionlistener

I have 3 buttons , update, delete and show history. I am trying to make sure that the table has a selected row before any of the 3 buttons can be implemented. The example I have here is the delete button. I have included the listener for the Delete JButton and a Selection Listener for the Table. I am unsure how to get the button to listen to the table Selection Listener first.

Delete action button listener

```
deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    

            isContactSelected();

            // Display yes/no dialog box over mainpanel when okButton is clicked
            int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainPanel, "Are you sure you wish to delete contact?", "Decision", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            // if yes is chosen system closed with an information box
            if (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (mainPanel, "Contact has been deleted", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                // if no is chosen system stays running
            } else if (answer == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {   


                // dont do anything


            }}
    });
```

check to see is row selected

```
public void isContactSelected(){

    ListSelectionModel selected  = table.getSelectionModel();
    //
    selected.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){

        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){

            int row = table.getSelectedRowCount();

            // if the number of rows selected is equal to 0
            if(row  > 0)

            {


            }else{

                System.out.println("Please select a contact");


            }

        }


    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just leave you buttons active & once pressed check if there is anything selected & if nothing is selected show something like a joptionpane

```
int row, column;

row = table.getSelectedRow();
table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column); //from here you can delete the row/column
```